# alert row index based on a field value extjs 3

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid panel, that is displaying values of database table. I want to know how can i get the row index of records that has for example a fieldname "COMPANY" with a field value "a".

```
  grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                                id:'users_gridpanel',
                                region:'center',
                                loadMask: {msg:"${tr.Loading}..."},
                                store: gridStore,
                                tbar:tlb,
                                cm: colModel,
                                stripeRows: true,
                                sm: _selctionModel,
                                plugins: [filters],
                                bbar:paging,
                                viewConfig:
                                {
                                    forceFit: true,
                                    headersDisabled:false
                                },




            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use store's [`findBy()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findBy) method (or `each()`, but `filterBy` already gets ID of the record as 2nd parameter) like

```
var ids = [];

myStore.findBy(
    function(record, id) {
        if(record.get('COMPANY') === 'a') {
            ids.push(id);
        }
        // return false so we continue loop through store data
        return false;
    },
    // Pass scope if needed
    this
);
```

`ids` array will contain all matched record IDs

Answer (score 0):

Returns the first matching index if available, returns -1 if not available.

```
var index = gridStore.find('COMPANY', 'a');
```